# Invalid escape sequence in literal with regex

Tags: ios, swift, string

I define a string with:

```
static let Regex_studio_tel = "^(0[0-9]{2,3}\-)?([2-9][0-9]{6,7})+(\-[0-9]{1,4})?$"
```

But there comes an issue:

> Invalid escape sequence in literal

The picture I token:

[image]

---

**Edit -1**

My requirement is match special plane numbers use Regex, such as:

My company have a special plane number：

```
028-65636688 or 85317778-8007
```

// `aaa-bbbbbbbb-ccc` we know the `aaa` is the prefix, and it means City Dialing Code， and `bbbbbbbb` is the main tel number, `cccc` is the landline telephone's extension number,

such as my company's landline telephone is `028-65636688`, maybe our company have 10 extension number: `028-65636688-8007 ,028-65636688-8006,028-65636688-8005` and so on.
Of course, it maybe have a ext-number at the end.

```
028-65636688-2559
```

Comment: TRY : static let Regex_studio_tel = "^(0[0-9]{2,3}'\'-)?([2-9][0-9]{6,7})+('\'-[0-9]{1,4})?$"

Comment: You may need some more examples to clarify your requirement. `65636688` is not valid, neither `028-65636688-85317778-8007` is not, OK?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Two character sequence `\` `-` is not a valid escape sequence in Swift String. When you need to pass `\` `-` to `NSRegularExpression` as pattern, you need to write `\\-` in Swift String literal.

So, your line should be something like this:

```
static let Regex_studio_tel = "^(0[0-9]{2,3}\\-)?([2-9][0-9]{6,7})+(\\-[0-9]{1,4})?$"
```

---

**ADDITION**

As Rob commented, minus sign is not a special character in regex when appearing outside of `[` `]`, so you can write it as:

```
static let Regex_studio_tel = "^(0[0-9]{2,3}-)?([2-9][0-9]{6,7})+(-[0-9]{1,4})?$"
```

Comment: @Rob, I wondered if I should note it, but it seems I should.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that your intent was to escape the `-` characters. But that's not necessary (and is incorrect). If your intent was to match just dashes, you should remove those backslashes entirely:

```
let pattern = "^(0[0-9]{2,3}-)?([2-9][0-9]{6,7})+(-[0-9]{1,4})?$"
```

---

Unrelated, but I'm suspicious of that `+` character. Did you really mean that you wanted to match one or more occurrences of `[2-9][0-9]{6,7}`? Or did you want to match exactly one occurrence?

Comment: thanks bro, I want to match the landline number, and I posted is not available in swift, match all of the landline number's will also consider `+`?

Comment: I don't know what format these landline numbers you want to match are. But I'm pretty sure it's not multiple sequences of `[2-9][0-0]{6,7}`. For example, your regex will match a sequence of the number 9 repeated 700 times. I can't believe that's what you intended. Maybe you can edit your question and show us actual examples of all of the sorts of strings you want to match.

Comment: @aircraft - OK, I see your updated your question. So, are you trying to match the full comma separated list of numbers, or do you want a regex that you can use to iterate through the numbers within that broader string?